# "vagrant up" printing hundreds of lines starting with "==> default:"

Tags: vagrant

Edit: It seems that all I had to do is wait. But I would still like to know if that output is supposed to mean anything to humans.

Windows 8.1 host.

I used the Git command line interface for windows instead of `cmd` so I can use my familiar linux CLI commands. I just ran the following two commands, the first of which ran without error, and the second of which seems to still be doing something:

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64-juju
$ vagrant up
```

The first command happened quickly and without error. But after the second command, although the virtual machine is up and running in virtual box (I logged in with user/pass "vagrant"), in the Windows Git CLI I am getting seemingly infinite output like that below. At first I thought maybe some configuration was still happening so I waited. But 30 minutes later it is still going.

```
==> default: :
==> default: 2
==> default: 9
==> default: :
==> default: 2
==> default: 3
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: 0
==> default: :
==> default: 0
==> default: 9
==> default: :
==> default: 0
==> default: 5
==> default:
==> default: 8
==> default: 8
==> default: 2
==> default: 1
==> default: 7
```

Ok wow, and a few minutes later finally something seems to be happening:

```
==> default: 6
==> default: 3
==> default: k
==> default: Bootstrapping Juju...
==> default: Bootstrapping environment "local"
==> default: Starting new instance for initial state server
==> default: Building tools to upload (1.25.3.1-trusty-amd64)
==> default: Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
==> default: Logging to /home/vagrant/.juju/local/cloud-init-output.log on remote host
==> default: Installing package: curl
==> default: Installing package: cpu-checker
==> default: Installing package: bridge-utils
==> default: Installing package: rsyslog-gnutls
==> default: Installing package: cloud-utils
==> default: Installing package: cloud-image-utils
==> default: Installing package: tmux
==> default: Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
==> default: Starting Juju machine agent (juju-agent-vagrant-local)
==> default: Bootstrap agent installed
==> default: -> local
==> default: Waiting for API to become available
==> default: Waiting for API to become available
==> default: Waiting for API to become available
==> default: Bootstrap complete
==> default: Taking a nap to let state server come up...
==> default: Added charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-48" to the environment.
==> default: Setting up Juju GUI dependencies...this may take a minute.
==> default: You can find the log in /var/log/juju-setup.log
==> default: You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
==> default: write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
==> default: Branched 25 revisions.
==> default: Taking a nap to let Juju Gui get setup
==> default:
==> default: Setting up transparent redirect for Juju-Gui
==> default: Redirecting localhost:6079 to 10.0.3.49:80
==> default:
==> default: Executing: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6079 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.49:80
==> default:
==> default: From your browser on your hosts, you should be able to
==> default: access the GUI by going to: http://127.0.0.1:6080
==> default:
==> default: Your password is: mACsz/qM
==> default: juju-gui start/running, process 20170
==> default: juju-gui start/running, process 20170
```

I just don't understand the UX philosophy there, where the user has no idea what is happening. How was I supposed to understand that output before?

Comment: You should contact directly the owner of the box and ask them what they wanted to show with those output. nobody else can tell you about it really

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Actually, you did just tell me one thing about it that I didn't know. Thank you. But I think it is a fairly popular official (?) ubuntu box (10,169 downloads, compared with 12,289,913 downloads for non-juju version ), so I will leave this question up for now in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: well 10k downloads is not that impressive neither and 10 versions in a month sounds like work in progress (which is a good thing, don't take me wrong, but you can expect that not everything is well finalized and the team prefer to ship often)

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yeah true. I am probably going to try the non juju one too ( not sure if I need juju ). If that one displays the same weird output then it is definitely a pretty strange problem that many people will be wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the author of the box either a) configuring it that way or b) not accounting for something specific to your setup which is throwing output into your terminal (eg. maybe they expected the box to be booted from a POSIX environment and not the Windows Git CLI).

As was suggested in the comments to the question, contacting the box owner or choosing a different box would help narrow down the issue. Common boxes which usually work without issue are those put out by hashicorp (the makers of Vagrant) or standard and popular ubuntu or debian boxes (such as ubuntu/trusty64).

Comment: This was 'ubuntu/trusty64-juju' from Ubuntu but perhaps you're right about the Windows Git CLI being a factor.

Comment: @ButtleButkus try to boot other boxes from that environment - if they also have problems that would help you identify if the Windows Git CLI is a factor.